# Upgrading to kernel 3.1 from 3.0.0-15

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, kernel

I've tried [this instruction to install kernel 3.1](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/11/how-to-install-kernel-31-on-ubuntu.html)
but when I checked my kernel version with `uname -r` command (after rebooting), there was no change and my kernel version was still shown as 3.0.0-15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this instructions to upgrade to kernel 3.2. Works like a charm and you can have 3.2 in your current ubuntu installation.

http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/01/install-upgrade-to-linux-kernel-3-2-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/

Comment: thanks but i prefer to upgrade to 3.1 so the risk would be smaller, wouldn't it?

Comment: @yinon: no, it would not.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to latest kernel is not always risky, if something does not work properly, you can always get back to previous versions of kernel installed on your computer.